# Traverse XML file to find products recursively

Tags: php, recursion, xml-parsing, simplexml

[image]I am trying to read remote XML file to find products in a specific category. I am facing issue because XML file has nested categories and each category has products. I need help in preparing a recursive function which will output products from a specific category given the category name.
Here is the code i have started with

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('https://www.deere.com/en/us-en.taxonomy');
    getProducts($xml);

    function getProducts($xml) {
        foreach ($xml as $obj) {
            if ($obj->getName() == 'en_us_tractors') { //if category name is en_us_tractors
                if ($obj->children()) {
                    foreach ($obj->children() as $child) {
                        echo '<h1>' . $child->name . '</h1>';
                        if ($child->products) {
                            foreach ($child->products as $product) {
                                foreach ($product as $p) {
                                    echo 'sku  is ' . $p->sku . '<br>';
                                    echo 'path  is ' . $p->path . '<br>';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }                       

                }


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be rather useful if we could see the actual XML file, or a `var_export($xml)` or at least a reasonaby representative example

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's availiable by the link. But I don't understand what to find

Comment: @RiggsFollyI need to find products node and then output products name and path from that node.

Comment: Ok, thats what this code does.... with a few minor errors. So what cant you do

Comment: @RiggsFolly the problem with my code is that it searches for top level category but if the category is down (nested with multiple level) then my code fails.

Comment: I think you had better tell us What output you are expecting

Comment: Xpath ? `//en_us_tractors/products/*/sku`

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have added screenshot of the XML input file and also highlighted what i want to extract from the XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple to use XPath to find the data, this finds all of the products inside the category you want...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://www.deere.com/en/us-en.taxonomy');
$products = $xml->xpath("//en_us_tractors//products/*");
foreach ( $products as $product ){
        echo $product->sku."/".$product->path.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: thank you @nigel-ren. I was not aware that xpath can simplify xml parsing.